# Call terminal input at start of bash script

Tags: xcode, bash, shell, terminal, yara

I downloaded Yara from Git. When I run yara from terminal, it works as I would expect.  I want to know if it's possible to create a bash script that would let me call yara and then execute my command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

yara -w /path/path/path works in terminal

yara -w in a shell script does not execute as I would want.

Comment: What's the issue you're seeing with latter (in a shell script)?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear.  It runs fine in the shell script, however, when I call the script from Xcode, it states "yara: command not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it from shell, your environment is set.

For e.g., if your default shell is bash, then `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` sets them (`/etc/profile` is sourced as well).

Via Xcode, this doesn't happen automatically. So, `$PATH` doesn't have the location for `yara`.

You may:

- Use the complete path for `yara` from `Xcode`
- OR Source `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` in `Xcode` (if there's such an option)) before using `yara`
- OR Configure the `$PATH` settings in `Xcode` to point to the location where `yara` is installed. You can find it by running `which yara` in the shell.

Comment: Glad, it helped!